# Class defines compareTo(...) and uses Object.equals()

Tags: java, warnings, findbugs, compareto

```
 public int compareTo(DynamicField other) {
     return other.wildcard.length() - wildcard.length();
 }

 boolean equals(DynamicField other) { 
    return compareTo(other) == 0; 
 }
```

I'm facing this issue. Can you Please suggest me how to solve this ? 
My method implementations are as above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `equals` method is not correctly defined, it should be:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
  ...
}
```

Something like this should work:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
  if (!(obj instanceof DynamicField))
     return false;
  return compareTo((DynamicField)obj) == 0;
}
```

If you're overriding a method of another class or implementing an interface method, you should always add `@Override`. If you defined it incorrectly, it should tell you something like:

```
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```